# AngularJS Datepicker - no date selected

Tags: angularjs, input, datepicker

I have a model that opens up a form to edit user information. The form has multiple input fields that are using the datepicker. Some of the date fields are not required. However, if one of the dates is empty in the database, then today's date is automatically filled in and it is saved once the user clicks the save button even if it is not intended to be saved.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
    <div>
       <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="editUser.DatesTemp" datepicker-options="dateOptions" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script file

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'gm.datepickerMultiSelect']);

// MAIN CONTROLLER
angular.module("myApp").controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.Data = data;
console.log(data);

   $scope.userEdit = function (index) {
       $scope.editUser = data.userInfo[index];
       //using moment to format date
       $scope.editUser.DatesTemp = moment($scope.editUser.Dates[0]).toDate();
   };

});

// DATE CONTROLLER
angular.module("myApp").controller("modalEditUserController", function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.postUpdate = function () {
       //using moment to format date
       $scope.editUser.Dates[0] = moment($scope.editUser.DatesTemp).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A');
   };
});

// DATE FILTER
angular.module("myApp").filter("asDate", function () {
   return function (input) {
      return new Date(input);
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [api](http://makingsense.github.io/moment-datepicker/), which I was previously unfamiliar with, it seems there are "Events" that can be called.  Perhaps a condition can be made using the "changeDate" call to set the date to null in the database if none is entered by the user.

Their code example:

```
$('#dp5').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){
        ....
    }
});
```

Maybe find a way to instantiate this in your code.

Also, not required, but a quick tip for writing controllers. The module can be declared as a variable and later used with each following controller/filter.  Just a short cut for the code.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'gm.datepickerMultiSelect']);

app.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http) {
   ...    
});
app.controller("modalEditUserController", function ($scope, $http) {
   ...
});
```